# Website Image logo Url

Tags: jquery, css, node.js

I want to get logo image url from this website   "**http://www.ford.com/**",I am using **jquery** selector for that,but my project are based on **Node js**.
            I think this logo has background-image in CSS so that I write this code but it is not run..

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$(".globalnav-header #badge a.logo .img").filter(function() {
    console.log( $(this).css('background-image'));
});
```

Comment: Since ford.com automatically redirects me to the hungarian site, I'm not sure about the markup, but did you correctly load jQuery?

Comment: If I go to ford.com, I'm redirected to another url for language selection! Maybe that's the isseu?

Comment: There is lots of redirection in ford's site. First, output the content of content that you fetch with cheerio

Comment: can you post your `HTML markup` because you can do this too using the `attr()`.

Comment: yes all of the other functions would correct work for this jquery

Comment: rockstar how can I extract logo image of ford website using attr().. i thing this is an text image..

Comment: nah, its wrong what I said. lemme check what i can do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.filter`. Try:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log( $(".globalnav-header #badge a.logo .img").css('background-image'));
```

---

I just tested this code on Ford's website like this:

Ford doesn't use jQuery, so I needed to include it before running the code:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
```

Then I ran my code and it worked.

```
> console.log( $(".globalnav-header #badge a.logo .img").css('background-image'));
url(http://www.ford.com/resources/ford/global/images/logo/fordoval_header_168x31.png)
```

Comment: Sounds like jQuery isn't loaded. Are you able to select other elements?

Comment: yes scott i am getting all the div img and span tag from this jquery but Css is not working..

Comment: You usually get that error when jQuery is not being used e.g. `(".globalnav-header #badge a.logo .img").css('background-image')` will error but if you have the $ it will not `$(".globalnav-header #badge a.logo .img").css('background-image')`